# How to transfer text to the attribute with xsl?

Tags: xml, xslt, scripting, adobe-indesign

I have a problem with getting the correct result for my xsl transformation. When I am exporting my xml document from Indesign, without any transformation, following code is generated:

```
<text>aerher<b>hea</b>rh er<i>haeh</i> rehe eageag</text>
```

it should however look like this:

```
<text value="aerher[b]hea[/b]rh er[i]haeh[/i] rehe eageag" />
```

Notice also, how `<b>` is transforming to `[b]`. Now my biggest problem is, that I am not even  getting all of my text selected. With the following transformation, my result looks like this:

```
<xsl:template match="text">
   <text value="{text()}"/>
</xsl:template> 

<text value="aerher"/>
```

How can I get the complete text including my Tags? I will find out myself how to transform `<b>` to `[b]`. I just can't figure out, why it is not selecting all of my text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`<b>` is not part of the text node(s) contained by the `<text>` element - it is *markup*. If you want to convert the markup to text (i.e. pseudo-markup), try something like:

```
<xsl:template match="text">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="b">
    <xsl:text>[b]</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>[/b]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="i">
    <xsl:text>[i]</xsl:text>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    <xsl:text>[/i]</xsl:text>
</xsl:template>
```